# How can I search for a string inside double quotes?

Tags: regex, string

I want to search for regex by separating each word and the string of double quotes.

For example, if I have a sentence like this

```
cmd -c \"reg query \\\"HKLM\\System\\CurrentSet\\\"\"
```

I should search by these groups.

```
[(cmd), (-c), (\"reg query \\\"HKLM\\System\\CurrentSet\\\"\")]
```

So I tried to make it like this with regular expression.

```
(([\'\"]).+?.*\")\s|(["A-Z\\a-z-]{0,})
```

But the search result came out like this.

```
[(cmd), (-c), (\"reg), (query), (\\\"HKLM\\System\\CurrentSet\\\"\")]
```

So I wonder how to write regular expressions to get these results.

`[(cmd), (-c), (\"reg query \\\"HKLM\\System\\CurrentSet\\\"\")]`

Comment: makes no sense ... rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this regex: `\\".*?(?<!\\\\)\\"|\S+`

#### Explanation

- `\\".*?` matches `\"` followed by anything with the ungreedy search.
- `(?<!\\\\)\\"` matches `\"` which is not preceded by `\\` (two slashes).
- `|\S+` means "or some non-space chars once or more".

#### Code

The PCRE version with PHP:

```php
$regex = '/\\\\".*?(?<!\\\\\\\\)\\\\"|\S+/m';
```

PHP test here: https://regex101.com/r/uEUn6d/1

The Python version:

```py
import re

regex = r"\\\".*?(?<!\\\\)\\\"|\S+"
```

Python test here: https://regex101.com/r/uEUn6d/3

Comment: Thank you. I added a little bit more and used this regular expression. `\\?\".*?(<!\\\\)?\\?\"|\S+` in Golang